# Java web app: JSON/web form binding

Tags: java, html, json, forms

I'm looking for a Java library that will help me build HTML forms from JSON objects, and in turn produce JSON objects from the data supplied to the forms.

That's basically all I need--I don't need XML support, Javascript form validation, or anything fancy. I just need to get data in and data out.

Does such a library exist? Thanks!

EDIT: for the curious, I'll be using Jetty with servlets as the backend.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I can't believe none has been created already... and the other answer's suggestion (json-simple) looked completely useless for this task unless I missed something

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether such a library exists, but I do know of [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), which really helped me a lot in my JSON encoding and decoding. With this library all you should need is a few additional steps to build your forms or build JSON objects.